# Не получается конвертировать Integer в String

Tags: java, строки, конвертация

Есть класс для работы с параметрами сетевых запросов

```
public class NeboParameters extends LinkedHashMap<String, Object> implements Serializable {

public NeboParameters() {
    super();
}

public NeboParameters(Map<String, Object> fromMap) {
    super(fromMap);
}

public static NeboParameters from(Object... params) {
    if (params.length % 2 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Params must be paired");
    }
    LinkedHashMap<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<>(params.length / 2);
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < params.length; i += 2) {
        result.put((String) params[i], (String) params[i + 1]);
    }
    return new NeboParameters(result);
}
}
```

Все значения должны конвертироваться в `String`.

Вот пример

```
NeboParameters params = NeboParameters.from(NeboConst.USER_ID, 3484192, NeboConst.MESSAGE, "Тест2");
```

Значение 3484192 не конвертируется в `String`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы привести объект к строке, используйте метод `String.valueOf`:

```
Object[] params = { 3484192, true };
for (Object obj : params)
{
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

Или, если уверены в том, что объекты не равны `null`, напрямую метод `toString`:

```
Object[] params = { 3484192, true };
for (Object obj : params)
{
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! )